# Issues with multiple circular progress bars

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

I've used the code from https://www.formget.com/css-progress-bar/#circular_progress_bar to make a circular progress bar and it worked fine, until I added a second one. I don't know how to change the amount of percentage that the progress bar goes for each one individually - can anyone help me how to do that? (:

jsfiddle.net/pw87wpyh/1

Comment: Please give us some of your code.

Comment: All the code I used is on the link I posted

Comment: YOUR CODE - not some blog entry link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pw87wpyh/

this is all i have

Comment: There is one progress bar and it seems to work. So where is the problem - with code!  - I know you have a problem with multiple progress bars. But if I would start to put multiple progress bars on a page and it just works, that would be no help for your, right? So please show us your code that does not work.

Comment: I tried adding a second one and changing max to respectively 80 and 20, but both of them goes to 80%. I don't know if that is what i'm supposed to do https://jsfiddle.net/pw87wpyh/1/

Comment: Ok. This is something we can work with and help you with. Please update your question with the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle has two elements with the id *progress_bar*. But a id for an html element **must be unique**. Thats why both go to 80%. Change the id for the second progress bar and then change the javascript code accordingly.

Tried that in your fiddle and had to change a bit more and added several ids: https://jsfiddle.net/pw87wpyh/2/

HTML code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar_container">
<div id="main_container">
<div id="pbar" class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
<div class="ppc-progress">
<div class="ppc-progress-fill" id="progress-fill"></div>
</div>
<div class="ppc-percents" id="ppc-percents">
<div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
<span>%</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<progress style="display: none" id="progress_bar" value="0" max="80"></progress>
</div>
</div>



<div class="bar_container">
<div id="main_container">
<div id="pbar2" class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
<div class="ppc-progress">
<div class="ppc-progress-fill" id="progress-fill2"></div>
</div>
<div class="ppc-percents" id="ppc-percents2">
<div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
<span>%</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<progress style="display: none" id="progress_bar2" value="0" max="20"></progress>
</div>
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var progressbar = $('#progress_bar');
max = progressbar.attr('max');
time = (1000 / max) * 5;
value = progressbar.val();

var progressbar2 = $('#progress_bar2');
max2 = progressbar2.attr('max');
time2 = (1000 / max2) * 5;
value2 = progressbar2.val();

var loading = function() {
if (value < max) {
value += 1;
addValue = progressbar.val(value);
}
if (value2 < max2) {
value2 += 1;
addValue2 = progressbar2.val(value2);
}

$('#progress_bar').html(value + '%');
$('#progress_bar2').html(value2 + '%');

var $ppc = $('#pbar'),
deg = 360 * value / 100;
if (value > 50) {
$ppc.addClass('gt-50');
}

var $ppc2 = $('#pbar2'),
deg2 = 360 * value2 / 100;
if (value2 > 50) {
$ppc2.addClass('gt-50');
}

$('#progress-fill').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
$('#progress-fill2').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg2 + 'deg)');

$('#ppc-percents span').html(value + '%');
$('#ppc-percents2 span').html(value2 + '%');

if (value == max) {
clearInterval(animate);
}
};

var animate = setInterval(function() {
loading();
}, time);
});
```

Change the styles as you need them.